# addon is not installed pro lighting studio

Tags: add-on

I have version 2.80 Blender. addon comes from version 2.80 and higher. the system says that the addon is installed but it does not appear in the list
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the forum. This forum is used to solve new problems blender users have, and hopefully have other users benefit from the solutions given. In order to help you with your problem, we need a clear title in English and a good explanation of the problem you have. What addon are you trying to install, do you have some screenshots of your installation? Give us some information to work with. This is not chat support, so we need all necessary information in your initial post. Thank you! :)

Comment: For issues regarding  paid for addons suggest using support provided by  the vendor.